# Is asking about comments on some new paper off topic?

Tags: discussion

I mean there is usually new interesting papers that I would like to share with you with some critical summary and then being able to discuss it. Think of a pseudo reading group. Is it off topic?

Answer (score 13):

I think this is fine as long as a working paper is publicly available online (such as though NBER or SSRN) and it is written in the form suitable to this website. That is, it must be a question that hypothetically has a definite answer. So, I don't think it would be appropriate to ask, for example, "What do you think about this paper?" Instead, an appropriate question would be something like "Is the author's argument about why his instrument is exogenous valid even if we believe [insert something here]?" or maybe even "What is the main contribution of this paper?"

Comment: The OP's idea is excellent and the moderator's suggestion the same.